# Pandas Bar Graph Axis

Tags: python, pandas

I'm making the graph linked below and I need to change the x-axis which belongs to the order of the data to the CCAA or city. How would I do this? Thanks!

```
data = data.sort_values(by=['Cases'], ascending=False)

Combined = data2[['Cases','Deaths','Recovered']].plot(kind='bar',[enter image description here][1] figsize=(10, 10), legend=True, fontsize=13 )
plt.show
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbtrL.png)

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Hg4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Specify the `xticks`

```
data2[['Cases','Deaths','Recovered']].plot(
        kind='bar', figsize=(10, 10),
        legend=True, fontsize=13, 
        xticks=data2.CCAA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert column `CCAA` to index before plot:

```
(data2.set_index('CCAA')[['Cases','Deaths','Recovered']]
      .plot(kind='bar', 
            figsize=(10, 10), 
            legend=True, 
            fontsize=13))
```